# robot_pose_ekf with an external sensor

Tags: ros, navigation, frame, robot-pose-ekf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the robot_pose_ekf package with my system, and am having trouble understanding what my tf tree should look like, and what frame the output of robot_pose_ekf is in.  My robot is microcontroller based and is not running ROS on-board.  Additionally it does not have any IMU information or visual sensing on-board.  It reports its pose estimate (based on odometry) in an /odom frame at a fixed frequency.  I have an external vision system tracking the robot as well.  The transform from the /sensor_optical frame to the /odom frame is static and known.  Every time the sensor transmits an estimate of the robot's position, I use this transform to transform the data into the /odom frame.

Thus, the /odom topic comes from the robot's odometry, and its header.frame_id is /odom, and its child_frame_id is /base_footprint.  The /vo topic comes from the external vision system, and its header.frame_id is /odom, and its child_frame_id is /base_footprint.  When I run the system the robot_pose_ekf package runs without any errors.  If I plot the pose published on the /odom and /vo topic, they are exactly what I expect, but the pose published on /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined topic is not what I expect.  Setting the covariances of the /vo topic to be very high, the pose output of /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined is then the same "shape" as that of /odom, but it must be in some odd coordinate system.

What am I doing wrong?  What frame should this pose be expressed in?  When I use tf2_visualization, I see that I have unconnected trees. robot_pose_ekf publishes a transform from /odom_combined -> /base_footprint, but that transform is unconnected from the rest of the tree.  I definitely believe this is a problem, but I am unsure how to fix it.  Finally, the pose published in /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined says its frame_id is odom (but it doesn't actually seem to be).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11682/robot_pose_ekf-with-an-external-sensor/) by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9031 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's ignore the vision system for a moment, and focus on wheel odometry and `robot_pose_ekf`. Your TF tree should look like this (also see [this ros-users thread](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/REP-105-base-footprint-and-odom-combined-td3330244.html)):

```
map --> odom_combined --> base_footprint --> base_link
```

... where

- `map --> odom_combined` is usually published by [amcl](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl) (*optional*)
- `odom_combined --> base_footprint` is published by [robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf)
- `base_footprint --> base_link` is a fixed link in your URDF.

The reason for this peculiar choice of frames is that in TF, each frame can only have one parent. Intuitively, one would like to have multiple parents of `base_footprint`:

- `odom --> base_footprint` for pure wheel odometry
- `odom_combined --> base_footprint` for EKF estimation
- `map --> base_footprint` for AMCL localization

Since this is not possible in TF, the frames are published as a chain (see above). The important part for your problem is that when using `robot_pose_ekf`, `tf` publishing from the wheel odometry has to be **switched off**. Instead, you should only publish `nav_msgs/Odometry` messages (using `odom_combined` as the header frame id), which form the input for `robot_pose_ekf` and can also be visualized in RViz.

In short:

- use `odom_combined` instead of `odom` everywhere (or the other way around, but be consistent about it)
- don't publish any TF messages, let `robot_pose_ekf` do that
- publish `nav_msgs/Odometry` messages for the wheel odometry and the overhead camera on the `/odom` and `/vo` topics, in both cases specifying `odom_combined` as the header frame id and `base_footprint` as the child_frame_id.

I hope that helps; otherwise, could you post your TF tree, showing the unconnected frames?

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on 2012-01-26**:
how can i implement base_footprint --> base_link transformation?

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-01-26**:
This is awesome info and should be somewhere in the navigation stack documentation.  It took me a long time to put all the pieces together the first time that we tried using move_base, but this is very clear.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-11-03**:
That's a good question, Jarvis. I think that is because there's a mismatch between REP-105 (which suggests "odom") and the way these frames are actually used on the PR2 and most other robots (which use "odom_combined"). See the mailing list thread linked in my answer.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2011-11-02**:
Thank you so much!  That totally got me straightened out, and solved the issues that I was having.  Given your explanation, I wonder why the geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped that is published by robot_pose_ekf has a hard-coded header.frame_id of "odom"?

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2016-07-07**:
@Güntherad @jarvisschultz ,thanks very much .But when i tried according to your answer ,i got a  problem when `rosrun  move_base node`  .It says "odom"  passed  to lookuptransform argument target_frame does not exist"  . how can i modify  move_base  to fix this tf problem,thanks very much .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having the same problem. I read your answer, but i am not able to totally understand how i can solve the problem. I am attaching my TF tree here. Can you please help me how i can resolve it? maybe post some code snippets.

[Screenshot from 2016-08-04 15:46:39.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1470350930221953.png)

---

Originally posted by [krishna43](https://answers.ros.org/users/22267/krishna43/) with karma: 63 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1